# Probability that zero doesn’t appear among k digits chosen independently and uniformly at random

Tags: probability

Sample space is $10^k$.

Number of sequences that do not contain $0$ is $9^k$.

So the probability is $(\frac{9}{10})^k$. Not sure if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: Your question should be written so that it has a meaning whithout the title.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.